# jmeter is not running script in the order it is written

Tags: jmeter, nested-loops

In jmeter, I'm using nested loop controllers, along with some JSR223 postprocessors inside each loop

Here's the order the script is written:

```
Loop Controller
    Loop Controller
        http request
    Endloop
    JSR223 postprocessor
Endloop
```

I want the script to first run the http request (multiple times), then after that looping is complete, run the JSR223 postprocessor, then repeat all that.

Instead, what is happening is it enters into the first Loop Controller, then runs the JSR223 postprocessor, then runs the second nested Loop Controller.

Why?  How do I get it to run the script in the order in which it's written from top to bottom and nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from using postprocessor , which is executed for every request in  [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), to sampler which executed once

> Some elements in the test trees are strictly hierarchical (Listeners, Config Elements, Post-Processors, Pre-Processors, Assertions, Timers), and some are primarily ordered (controllers, samplers).

Another option is to add it under Sampler which will  execute it omce after sampler

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  That was my issue. I was using a postprocessor, thinking because I wanted it to run after (the post part) the previous request, when I should have used a sampler.  As soon as I switched it, it fixed my script flow!!!

Answer (score 0):

JSR223 PostProcessor is being executed **after** each [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in its [Scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/), in your case after each iteration of the HTTP Request sampler.

If you want to run it only once - either put [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler at the place of the JSR223 PostProcessor and make the JSR223 PostProcessor **a child** of the Flow Control Action sampler.

Otherwise you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of the JSR223 PostProcessor, if you don't want the JSR223 Sampler to appear in test results - put [`SampleResult.setIgnore()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) function somewhere in your script.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri!  I switched my JSR223 postprocessors to JSR223 samplers, and that fixed my script!